# Drag and Drop columns in react-table version 6

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, react-table

What is the best way to drag and drop columns in react-table version 6. Are there any already available plugins that I can use or should I implement it on my own since I am using version 6 of react-table. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cGYeNFsiP0

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beautiful-dnd https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable